# PCF (blue/green deployment) - How to segment/route users based on their attributes

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, blue-green-deployment

I am trying to find a solution for user segmentation on PCF for blue/green deployment. I want to deploy two versions of a Java app on PCF, say a BLUE version and a GREEN version. Now, I want to route a specific group of users to GREEN and the rest to BLUE. I need to know if there is a way to have a gateway (such as zuul) to route users  based on their attributes. Not all required users attributes are in the header of the request -- they are stored in a database. When the request comes, the user id is in the request. But before segment/route users to BLUE/GREEN, I need to retrieve some of their info from the database.

Any comment/suggestions will be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything in CloudFoundry that would provide this capability. The best you can do with CF is to use routes to push traffic to different places, this is what's historically been done with blue/green deployment.

If you need more custom control, like what you're describing, you'd need to have an additional layer of routing that implements your custom routing requirements.

Since you mentioned Java, I would suggest looking at [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway). It is a very flexible way to route traffic.

You'd set things up such that all of your traffic is sent through a mapped public route on CF to an SCG app that you've pushed. The SCG app would then route traffic to your actual applications, this could happen over public routes, or what's nicer is to use CloudFoundry container networking and the internal routes. In this way, you can force all traffic to go through your gateway because there is no public access to the other apps.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#internal-routes

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your answer. I have a question. Assume I customize spring cloud gateway to route users to either blue or green based on information that are cached in Redis. For example, for each incoming request, route to green if a user-id is cached and route to blue if not cached.  What happens if a user is working in blue and for some reason cache is updated and this user's id is now cached (meaning that all requests should now go to green)? Assuming that blue UI and services are version 1.0 and green UI and services are version 2.0. I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I think that would ultimately be app-dependent. What I can say for sure is that you'd have a user sending requests to an app, suddenly that user's requests would start going to what is effectively a totally different app. Maybe that new app understands the request? maybe it doesn't and it returns 404? Even if it does understand them, it probably won't have a session for that user or any state that the user might have had, so you could see 401/403 auth errors or other error responses. Again, it depends on the apps and how different they are.

Comment: Agreed! Thank you Daniel!